# WAMP alias point to IP instead of directory

Tags: webserver, ip-address, wampserver

WAMP allows us create alias that can point other drive e.g. point to external dive (G), moreover, can I point to IP instead of point to drive?

Example point to `http://xxx.xxx.xxx/test` (Note: this is the same LAN network just different PC).

Answer (score 1):

Add that domain in hosts:

```
C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc
```

`127.0.0.1 domainname.com`

Answer (score 0):

Err, WAMP should listen on `127.0.0.1` by default, though security settings may restrict it to public access. If that PC has its own IP as well, then the content should be served over that as well.

Please re-phrase your question and we'd be happy to assist in fixing specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Virtual Host, nor Alias can do this. What you can do is to create a named virtual host on the other PC for example foobar, that points to that directory, and setup your hosts file to point to the other PC with the name of foobar.

This way your PC knows where to look for `http://foobar/`.

**This only works with a FixIP environment.**

Comment: This will work with a redirect as well, where yourhost/test will redirect to yourdestination/test.